# Object enter event "string to decimal not valid"

Tags: vb.net

I have VB program which concatenates decimals of 2 categories, income and expenses.

For some reason incomeTextBox.Enter and expensesTextBox.Enter has weird behavior, saying:

> Please enter numeric value for expenses

when I use either tab key or mouse to select other InputBox even after inputting an integer (which IsNumeric=True).

I also get error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Decimal' is not valid.

Also, this is VB, not VB.Net, but there is no VB tag??

```
Option Explicit On
Public Class MainForm

Public decexpenses, decincome As Decimal
Public dectotalexpenses As Decimal = 0
Public dectotalincome As Decimal = 0

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox("Use Enter key to enter values.")
End Sub

Private Sub expensesTextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles expensesTextBox.Enter
    Dim expenses = expensesTextBox.Text
    If IsNumeric(expenses) = False Then
        MsgBox("Please enter numeric value for expenses.")
    End If
    expensesTextBox.Text = ""
    decexpenses = CDec(expenses)
    dectotalexpenses = decexpenses + dectotalexpenses
End Sub

Private Sub incomeTextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles incomeTextBox.Enter
        Dim income = incomeTextBox.Text
        If IsNumeric(income) = False Then
        MsgBox("Please enter numeric value for income.")
    ElseIf IsNumeric(income) = True Then
        decincome = CDec(income)
        dectotalincome = decincome + dectotalexpenses
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that (;

Comment: The `Enter` event is raised if the user "enters" the `TextBox` the first time, probably the text is empty at this point which raises your exception. Use `Decimal.TryParse`

Comment: @TimSchmelter how would I do that? I am already using IsNumeric. And the problem is it gives me Enter event even when I don't use Enter on keyboard.

Comment: @ThomasShera: `Enter`-event has nothing to do with using the `Enter`-key. It means the user _enters_ the `textBox` which happens if the `TextBox` gets focus. So if it doesn't have focus and the user clicks into it or uses the keyboard(ALT-key) to switch focus. You probably want to use a different event like the `TextChanged`-event or use another approach like using a separate button that triggers your logic.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Or use the correct tool, a [NUD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control ;)

Comment: Oh, btw, in winforms you validate user input by handling the `Validating` and `Validated` events.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead of using Enter for the raise event I would use Text_Changed and use the KeyDown for Enter. Once the Text is Entered then they click enter on the textbox the routine will run Example the below:

```
Private Sub expensesTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles expensesTextBox.KeyDown
    Dim dectotalexpenses As Decimal = 0
    Dim dectotalincome As Decimal = 0

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        Dim value As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim decincome As Decimal
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(value, decincome) Then
            MsgBox("Please enter numeric value for expenses.")
            Return
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Enter` event is raised if the  `TextBox` gets focus the first time, probably the text is empty at this point which raises your exception.

In your code you are also netiher using `If...Else` nor returning if the value is not numeric, so `CDec(expenses)` gets executed anyway which causes the exception. Also, instead of `IsNumeric` use `Decimal.TryParse`:

```
Private Sub expensesTextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles expensesTextBox.Enter
    Dim value As String = expensesTextBox.Text
    Dim decincome As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(value, decincome) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter numeric value for expenses.")
        Return
    End If

    dectotalexpenses = decincome + dectotalexpenses
End Sub
```

You should also use a different event like `TextBox.TextChanged`.